# How to set argument VALUE in three double quotas

Tags: vbscript

I need to get argument in my VB script (argument is **PC1** )
and set it to another parameter with three double quotas
so finally I will print this PARAM with double quota

So I try this

```
  Dim ServerName
  ServerName = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
  PARAM = """ServerName"""
  Wscript.Echo PARAM
```

but I VB print

```
    "ServerName"
```

in place to print

```
    "PC1"
```

please advice what need to change in my VB script in order to print that: **"PC1"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
PARAM = """" & ServerName & """"
```

In your original sample the `"""ServerName"""` is simply being interpreted as a string.  It doesn't try to resolve the contents of the string to any variables.  My solution uses string concatenation to add quotes around the current value of `ServerName`